# Returning more than one number in a python list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] * 2
        return x[i]

print double_list(n)
```

For some reason this python script is only returning the first item in the list instead of all three when it runs... Can someone please help me?!

Comment: Hint: Check where your `return` statement is.

Comment: Hint: don't make a custom function for what already exists in a builtin

Comment: @Jivan which built-in will multiply all the values in a list by a scaler?

Comment: @wwii list comprehensions (or `for i in my_list` loops for that matter) are here for this kind of stuff - the accepted answer cumulates every non-Pythonic way of possibly doing what the OP, in fine, wants

Comment: @Jivan a list comprehension is not a [*built-in*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html)

Comment: @wwii what I meant is a ready-made solution already built into Python by design - but you're right, it's not a built-in. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double_list(x):
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        x[i]*=2
    return x

print double_list(n)
```

Try this.Returning the list, also check how we re-define variables with arithmetical operations.

Answer (score 5):

Use a **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)** instead.

```
double_list = [ x*2 for x in n ]
```

Same result, four times shorter, a trillion times more readable.

**[Because readability counts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)**.

Answer (score 3):

1. Change the `return` statement so that it is not indented to be part of the `for` block.
2. Return the list instead of an item from the list.

   ```
   def double_list(x):
       for i in range(0, len(x)):
           x[i] = x[i] * 2

       return x
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = [3, 5, 7]

def double_list(x):
    t=[i*2 for i in x]
    return t

print (double_list(n))
```

Another short way for that.

Answer (score 0):

to add to the options:

```
def double_list(x):
    return map(lambda num: num*2, x)

print double_list([2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: this would be better if not wrapped in a pointless extra function

Comment: In Python 3 it's possible to have:`>>> list(map((2).__mul__, [2, 3, 4]))`
`[4, 6, 8]` not that you'd ever want to